# Remove rows where value is *not* in column on other sheet

Tags: formula, libreoffice-calc

I have a LibreOffice Calc file with two sheets. Sheet 2 has just one column A with lots of numbers. In sheet 1, column A of every row also holds a number. I want to remove all rows from sheet 1 that have a value in column A which does *not* appear *anywhere* in column A of sheet 2.

Filters don't seem to do the trick, as they don't have a "value must be contained in some column" operator.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enter the following formula in cell B1 of Sheet1:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2.A:A,1, 0)),"",A1)
```

Then drag to fill this formula down column B.  This shows empty cells for all rows that do not occur in Sheet2.

To remove the empty rows, sort on column B (Data -> Sort).  Then select and delete the empty rows (Edit -> Delete Rows).

Comment: Works great, but I had to substitute the "," with ";" for separating the arguments. Thanks!

Comment: Commas separating arguments works as of now.

Comment: @DarrelUlm: Commas only work if they are set as the function separator in *Tools > Options > LibreOffice Calc > Formulas*. Semicolons work no matter what the setting, although as far as compatibility, they do not work in MS Excel.