# How to filter rows based on specific values in Libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a table with several columns.

[image]

I want only the lines where `target` value is different from `alg` value. In this case where `target` is **1** and `alg` is **0**. So, line 2, 4 and 5 should stay and line 3 should be removed. How to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a column that determines whether the row should be removed.  The formula for D2 is `=B2=C2`, and this is filled down to D5.

```
id      target  alg     remove row  string
11011   1       0       FALSE       hello
111     1       1       TRUE        this is
111     1       0       FALSE       car
112     1       0       FALSE       ship
```

To hide the rows, go to Data -> More Filters -> Standard Filter.  Set criteria to `remove row` = FALSE.  If desired, column D can be hidden by right-clicking on D and choosing Hide Columns.

Alternatively, to completely remove the rows, sort by column D and then select and delete all rows where column D is TRUE.  Finally, delete column D.

Related: [LibreOffice / OpenOffice Calc: Remove rows where value is *not* in column on other sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569473/libreoffice-openoffice-calc-remove-rows-where-value-is-not-in-column-on-oth?rq=1)